# Seleccionar diferencias entre dos tablas sql

Tags: sql

Necesito seleccionar todos los campos de las entradas que tengan diferencias entre dos columnas de dos tablas diferentes.

tablas: wow_eu_leadder_3v3 y wow_eu_leadder_3v3_old
columnas a comprobar: rating y ranking

Comment: Hola Akond, deberías leer [ask] en el centro de ayuda, donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus publicaciones. Por ejemplo, tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato (es difícil de leer), no termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres (¿a qué te refieres con que tengan diferencias?), y puede estar insuficientemente etiquetada (sería bueno que añadieras la base de datos que estás usando). También te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para ver el funcionamiento básico del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Me funcionó con esto:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM wow_eu_leadder_3v3 a,wow_eu_leadder_3v3_old b
WHERE a.name = b.name
  AND a.realm_id = b.realm_id
  AND a.rating <> b.rating;
```